# My Jest test hangs when I try to reach the Firebase Emulator I have running

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, jestjs, firebase-tools

The test is here - I am currently setting up jest tests with my project so this is not a complete test.

```js
import { expect, jest, describe, test, beforeAll, beforeEach, afterAll } from "@jest/globals";
import { firebaseDB, firebaseStorage } from "../firebaseprovider";
import { ref, set, get } from "firebase/database";

beforeAll(async () => {
    console.log("Running ArtworkProvider Tests");

    const fbRef = ref(firebaseDB, "test");
    const snapshot = await get(fbRef); // Hang occurs here
    console.log(snapshot.val())

})
```

https://github.com/jhengineerartist/art-website/blob/jest-test-add/src/lib/providers/test/artworkprovider.test.tsx

The issue I am getting is that the beforeAll function just... hangs.  I can extend the timeout to 20 second and it just hangs on the await get(...)

I verified I can connect to the port I'm using for the database by doing the following from the terminal

```
telnet localhost 9000

Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
```

so I dont think the issue is the port is unreachable.
I also don't see any indication of the set function being called in the emulator logs.

Can I get some advice on troubleshooting this further or an idea of what the root cause might be? This has me scratching my head given the lack of a useful log and a simple hang...

Started up firebase emulator

Started up jest test with the NODE_ENV variable set to test. This enables the connectDatabaseEmulator and related behavior:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
    config.databaseURL = process.env.TEST_FIREBASE_DATABASEURL as string
    console.log(JSON.stringify(config));
}

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(config);
const firebaseDB = getDatabase(firebaseApp);
const firebaseStorage = getStorage(firebaseApp);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
    connectStorageEmulator(firebaseStorage, "localhost", 9199);
    connectDatabaseEmulator(firebaseDB, "localhost", 9000);
}
```

https://github.com/jhengineerartist/art-website/blob/jest-test-add/src/lib/providers/firebaseprovider.ts

Attempting to do a simple get on the realtime database in my emulator, but the program hangs during the await get(...).

I expected any kind of response - even a failure would have allowed me to debug more clearly what was wrong with my configuration of the emulator and the test.

Comment: Did you follow the related documentation? https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests

Comment: On Stack Overflow, [do not require the reader to use links to external information](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/more-advice#dont-require-external-and-off-site-resources). Everything should be in the question itself so future readers always have immediate access to it. If you have code, copy and paste it into the question so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: Thanks! I added the relevant snippets above the links.

Comment: I did check out the documentation at [the firebase documentation site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests) and in fact in my master branch for this little project I already had the "initializeTestEnvironment" method setup. But I took it out when I saw other projects didn't use this api to setup their emulator, and that the api had changed (there is no longer any initializeTestApp function exposed so I assumed the use case for this had changed since the documentation was added).  I'm still very much exploring how to setup this test framework and the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue and I'm not sure yet what is happening exactly, only that it's related to using the *jsdom testing environment*, but I did manage to work around the problem.

When initializing the `firestore` instance, use `initializeFirestore()` instead of `getFirestore()` and make sure to pass the `useFetchStreams: false` option:

```
const testFirestore = initializeFirestore(testApp, {
  useFetchStreams: false,
})
```

> Note: you may get a type error, as the property is not exposed publicly anymore.

The default for `useFetchStreams` is `true` since `firebase@v9` and it seems that the `jsdom` environment is not properly supporting `fetch readable streams`. By setting it to `false`, firestore fallbacks to using `XHR` for streaming data.

Here's the open issue on the Firebase JS SDK repository: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7808